# Is there an interesting (perhaps geometric) interpretation of the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

There seem to be various theorems linked to a "Mean Value Theorem for Integrals".

Consider the following theorem

> Theorem 1: If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $m\leq f(x)\leq M$ for all $x \in
>  [a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f(x)dx=(b-a)\mu$ for some $\mu$ with
> $m\leq\mu\leq M$ (Spivak, Ch. 13, Problem 23a).

$\mu$ is the average value of the $f$ on $[a,b]$, which is

$$\mu = \frac{\int_a^b f(x)dx}{b-a}\tag{1}$$

Now consider a function $f$ that is continuous.

Being continuous, it is both integrable and bounded on $[a,b]$. Since these are the two assumptions of Theorem 1, we can assert that there is a $\mu$ satisfying $(1)$.

But we can go further: we can choose $m$ and $M$ to be the min and max values of $f$ on $[a,b]$, and thus by the Intermediate Value Theorem we can conclude that $f$ takes on the value $\mu$ in $(1)$ at some $\xi \in [a,b]$.

Therefore, we have

> Theorem 2: if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^b
>  f(x)dx=(b-a)f(\xi)$ for some $\xi \in [a,b]$.

This basically says that given a closed interval and a continuous function $f$, we can compute the average value of the function on the interval, and $f$ takes on this average value at some point in the interval.

This average value happens to be the slope between the antiderivative of $f$ evaluated at $a$ and at $b$. Ie, there is some point in the interval at which the derivative (of the antiderivative) equals the slope of the antiderivative at the endpoints. This is the Mean Value Theorem that one usually sees when one learns about derivatives.

But now consider in addition to a continuous $f$ on $[a,b]$, a function $g$ that is integrable and nonnegative on $[a,b]$. It is possible to show that

$$\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=f(\xi)\int_a^b g(x)dx\tag{2}$$

for some $\xi \in [a,b]$.

In Spivak, this is what is called the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals. Unlike the Mean Value Theorem introduced in the chapter on derivatives, which was shown in the main text as an important theorem, this Mean Value Theorem for Integrals seems less prominent, appearing only in a problem.

Furthermore, when I check Wikipedia, there seems to be a "Second Mean Value Theorem for Definite Integrals" which seems slightly different from the result from Spivak.

**My question is:** is there an intuitive (perhaps geometric) explanation about what these theorems (Spivak's MVT for Integrals, and perhaps the Wikipedia Second MVT for Definite Integrals) are saying?

Note that it is also possible to show $(2)$ when $g$ is nonpositive.

$(2)$ is not, however, necessarily true if $g$ is not nonpositive or nonnegative. A simple counterexample is $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

One interpretation of $(1)$ could be: for a nonnegative continuous function $f(x)$ the integral over $[a,b]$ represents the area of the region bounded by $x=a,$ $x=b$, $y=0$ and $y=f(x).$ By the mean value theorem there exists a rectangle with base $b-a$ and height $f(\xi)$ with the same area. Unfortunately I am unable to draw a picture to illustrate that.

Concerning formula (2), assume both function are nonnegative. Consider a nonhomogeneous fence along the segment $[a,b],$ with height at $x$  equal $g(x)$ and mass density equal $f(x).$ I assume that mass density is constant vertically. Then the integral represents the total mass of the fence. The right hand side is equal the surface of the fence times a density for some value $\xi,$ i.e. the mass of the homogeneous fence with mass density $f(\xi).$